# how can i convert hashmap to array?

Tags: java

I want to convert hashMap (String,Integer)
such as String[], Integer[].

But I heard the information about hashmap.keyset().array() and hashmap.values().array() doesn't match, so it is dangerous,

then, is it possible?

```
        for(Map.Entry<String,Integer> val: hashmap.entrySet()) {
            int n = 0;
            String key[n]=val.getKey();
            int value[n]=val.getValue();
            n++;
        }
```

Comment: you can use stream on hashmap.entrySet()

Comment: _Why_ do you want to do this? The pattern you mention is called _parallel arrays_, and it is usually better to go to effort not to do that in the first place.

Comment: Now I am making an application which counts the number of user's watching record and put it order by genre, so i need each array and put it in chart

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to convert it to a single array then:

```
Object[] array = hashmap.entrySet().toArray();
```

or

```
Map.Entry<String, Integer>[] array = 
        hashmap.entrySet().toArray(Map.Entry<?, ?>[0]);
```

(Possibly an unchecked conversion is required, but it is safe ...).

If you want parallel arrays for the keys and values:

```
String[] keys = new String[hashmap.size()];
Integer[] values = new Integer[hashmap.size()];
int i = 0;
for (e: hashmap.entrySet()) {
    keys[i] = e.getKey();
    values[i] = e.getValue();
    i++;
}
```

There is probably a neater solution using the Java 8+ stream functionality.